# mongoose object method is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am trying to create a route to register users for my application, but I ran into a problem. When hitting the `/register` route, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: user.setPassword is not a function at
```

Here is my code:

**models/Users.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {type: String, lowercase: true, unique: true},
  hash: String,
  salt: String
});

UserSchema.methods.setPassword = function(password){
  this.salt = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');
  this.hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 1000, 64).toString('hex');
};

UserSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password) {
  var hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 1000, 64).toString('hex');
  return this.hash === hash;
};

UserSchema.methods.generateJWT = function() {

  // set expiration to 60 days
  var today = new Date();
  var exp = new Date(today);
  exp.setDate(today.getDate() + 60);

  return jwt.sign({
    _id: this._id,
    username: this.username,
    exp: parseInt(exp.getTime() / 1000),
  }, 'SECRET');
};

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

**routes/index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var mongoose = require('mongoose'); 


var User = mongoose.model('User');

router.post('/register', function(req, res, next){
  if(!req.body.username || !req.body.password){
    return res.status(400).json({message: 'Please fill out all fields'});
  }

  var user = new User();

  user.username = req.body.username;
  user.setPassword(req.body.password);

  user.save(function (err){
    if(err){ return next(err); }

    return res.json({token: user.generateJWT()})
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//MongoDB Setup
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('./models/Users');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/images');

var passport = require('passport');
require('./config/passport');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var app = express();
app.use(passport.initialize());
.
.
.
module.exports = app;
```

I'm fairly new to the MEAN stack, and after scouring the code for a few hours I can't see why things are going wrong.

Comment: I like how you are storing the salt and hash. Haven't seen this done this way before. Most code i see only just stores a password in the db

Comment: It's safer this way, even if a leak happened, no plaintext is stored. I got it from thinkster.io.

Comment: thanks for the link to thinkster.io too bad they don't have an rss feed i would like to add their tuts to feedly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny: Always make sure your files are not saved in some funky location. I had a copy of `Users.js` in my `stylesheets/` folder and that was the copy I was working on this entire time. The copy in `models/` in the meantime was full of little buggy things that were easy to spot.

Answer (score 5):

Below is my code and it works for me.

```js
-----User Model
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const validator = require('validator');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Pleae enter your name']
    },
    email:{
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please enter your email address'],
        unique: true,
        validate: [validator.isEmail, 'Please enter a valid email address']
    },
    role: {
        type: String,
        enum:{
            values: ['user', 'employer'],
            message : 'Please select your role'
        },
        //required: [true, 'Please select role that is required'],
        default: 'user'
    },
    password :{
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please enter password for your account'],
        minlength: [8, 'Your password must be a t leeast 8 characters long'],
        select: false
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    resetPasswordToken: String,
    resetPasswordExpire: Date
});

//Encryting Passwords before Saving
userSchema.pre('save', async function(next){
    this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10);
});

//Return JSON web token
userSchema.methods.getJwtToken = function(){
    return jwt.sign({id: this._id}, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
        expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_TIME
    });
}

//Compare password in database
userSchema.methods.comparePassword = async function(enterPassword){
    return await bcrypt.compare(enterPassword, this.password);
}


module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);







-----Auth Controller
const User = require('../models/users');
const catchAsyncErrors = require('../middlewares/catchAsyncErrors');
const ErrorHandler = require('../utils/errorHandler');

//Register a new user ==> /api/v1/user/register

exports.registerUser = catchAsyncErrors(async(req, res, next) => {
    const { name, email, password, role} = req.body;
    
    const user = await User.create({
        name,
        email,
        password,
        role
    });

    //Create JWT Token
    const token = user.getJwtToken();

    res.status(200).json({
        succes: true,
        message: 'User created succesfully',
        data: user,
        token: token
    })
});



//Loguin user => /api/v1/login
exports.loginUser = catchAsyncErrors( async(req, res, next) =>{
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    if(!email || !password){
        return next (new ErrorHandler('Please enter email and password'), 400);
    }

    //Finding user in database
    const user = await (await User.findOne({email})).isSelected('+password');

    if(!user){
        return next(new ErrorHandler('Invalid Email or Password', 401));
    }

    //Check if passwoerd is correct
    const isPasswordMatched = await user.comparePassword(password);

    if(!isPasswordMatched){
        return next (new ErrorHandler('Invalid Email or Password', 401));
    }

    //Create JSOBN Web Token
    const token = user.getJwtToken();

    res.status(200).json({
        succes: true,
        token
    })

})
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to do this:

**models/Users.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {type: String, lowercase: true, unique: true},
  hash: String,
  salt: String
});

UserSchema.methods.setPassword = function(password){
  this.salt = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');
  this.hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 1000, 64).toString('hex');
};

UserSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password) {
  var hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 1000, 64).toString('hex');
  return this.hash === hash;
};

UserSchema.methods.generateJWT = function() {

  // set expiration to 60 days
  var today = new Date();
  var exp = new Date(today);
  exp.setDate(today.getDate() + 60);

  return jwt.sign({
    _id: this._id,
    username: this.username,
    exp: parseInt(exp.getTime() / 1000),
  }, 'SECRET');
};

// exports the user schema
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

**routes/index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
var User = require('models/user'); // require the user model in the correct path

// line removed
//var User = mongoose.model('User');

router.post('/register', function(req, res, next){
  if(!req.body.username || !req.body.password){
    return res.status(400).json({message: 'Please fill out all fields'});
  }

  var user = new User();

  user.username = req.body.username;
  user.setPassword(req.body.password);

  user.save(function (err){
    if(err){ return next(err); }

    return res.json({token: user.generateJWT()})
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: The proposed fix throws the following error: `User is not a function`